# Why does my controller require the params hash to be repetitively nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I currently have the following situation:

ChallengeRequestsController #new - creates a ChallengeRequest along with another model needing a *recpient_id*.

```
def create
  @challenge_request = ChallengeRequest.new(challenge_params)

  recipient = User.find(params.require(:recipient_id))

  # Rest of method redacted.
end

def challenge_params
  params.require(:challenge_request).permit(:action)
end
```

With this controller, I have an RSpec test as follows:

```
RSpec.describe ChallengeRequestsController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST #create" do

    context "with valid challenge request" do
      let(:valid_challenge_request) { build(:challenge_request) }

      context "with non-exisistent recpient id" do
        it "throws an error" do
          expect{
            post :create, :params => {
              :challenge_request => {
                :challenge_request => valid_challenge_request
              },
              :recipient_id => 10000
            }
          }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Just for reference, here's the Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :challenge_request do
    action { Faker::LeagueOfLegends.champion }
  end
end
```

All of this code works and the test passes, my question is how can I refactor this in a way that I don't need to use the ugly nesting in the request?

```
:challenge_request => {
  :challenge_request => valid_challenge_request
}
```

When posting the request without this nesting:

```
post :create, :params => {
  :challenge_request => valid_challenge_request,
  :recipient_id => 10000
}
```

The challenge_request is empty when the ChallengeRequestController receives the request.

Comment: When you say "when posting the request without this nesting" can you share the full code along with how you determine that the challenge_request is empty?

Comment: @draganstankovic When running without the nesting,
`:params => {
                :challenge_request => valid_challenge_request,
                :recipient_id => 10000
`

I get the following error:
`
<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: challenge_request> with backtrace:
`

To confirm the empty challenge_request, I printed out the params in the ChallengeRequestController:
`
<ActionController::Parameters {"challenge_request"=>"", "recipient_id"=>"10000", "controller"=>"challenge_requests", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably work if you change your `valid_challenge_request` to be a hash of attributes instead of the model itself.

```
let(:valid_challenge_request) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:challenge_request) }
```

You're trying to send along an instance of a model as a parameter to a controller, and something is doing something (I can't find what's doing what to the model) to try and coerce it into something that a browser might send the controller. That conversion is turning the model into an empty string, which is not **`present` or the value `false`** and thus causes the `require` to throw the `ParameterMissing`

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation and works as expected :)